# Issue converting object column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am facing an issue converting an object column that has years only (1965-2020) to a datetime data type (DD/MM/YYYY).

I have used the pd.datetime function but for some reason all the rows has the value 1970 now.

any help would be really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

convert to string before parsing to datetime:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1965, 2020]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str))

#    year   datetime
# 0  1965 1965-01-01
# 1  2020 2020-01-01
```

If you feed pd.to_datetime with a numeric value (e.g. integer 1965), it will be interpreted as nanoseconds since 1970-01-01 by default (Unix epoch). This is why you got year 1970 for all input years.

see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html),

- `unit  :  str, default ‘ns’`
- `origin  :  scalar, default ‘unix’`

Comment: How about `df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y').dt.year`

Comment: @GurjotMahi that would basically do the opposite, no? OP wants "datetime data type (DD/MM/YYYY)" according to the question, your code snippet however would give you the year as an interger

Comment: True. Does that remain relevant if we delete `dt.year` part?

Comment: @GurjotMahi sure, could be helpful (w/o `.dt.year`), also works if `df['year']` is of dtype int. Setting the `, format='%Y'` explicitly is also good for readability, makes clear what's happening.

Comment: thank you, @MrFuppes answer solved the problem. thank you all for your help :)

Comment: @SM1987: if the answer solves your problem, consider [accepting it as solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).